# Update a variable in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, web, frontend

I have a web app written in vue in which the user has to submit an amount. I want to create an integer variable `total_amount` that updates at each run. For eg, one user submits 50$, so `total_amount` should update to 50$, then another user submits 25$, then `total_amount` should update to 75$.
So, I want a variable that updates it's value at the click of a button and then I'm returning this updated value to a function on the same page.
Is there a way to achieve this on the frontend side itself, without any database or backend assistance?

```
data() {
    return {
      total_amount: 0
    }
}
```

I initialized `total_amount` in this way, but the problem is that it starts from 0 at each run, so it does not add on the previous amount rather just returns the current value.

Comment: It's technically possible. You'd need some way to persist the data on the backend (if not a database solution, then perhaps a simple JSON file), and the frontend would need to query the backend for that data in order to synchronize any changes.

Comment: You can also use local storage in the browser, load the variable from the local storage in the create() and update it in the button method or  doing a watch on the variable

Comment: @Dicren this is incorrect, Read the question.

Comment: @Pradyut, What web server are you using? this will help with using Tonys solution.

Comment: @MichaelMano The project is using traefik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use a backend server or a database to store that value , since this value gets accessed by deferent clients and session so it needs to be stored like a variable or a column in your database ,see below simple node Js backend

```
var http = require('http');

var total_amount= 0;

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    total_amount++;

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });

    res.write('Hello!\n');

    res.write('We have had ' + total_amount+ ' visits!\n');

    res.end();

 

});

server.listen(9090);

console.log('server running...')
```